# Как гарантировать неизменность кода програмного обеспечения?

Tags: лицензирование, opensource

Допустим я продаю кому-то своё ПО вместе с исходным кодом, но я не хочу чтоб была изменена та или иная его часть, не хочу чтоб человек, которому я его продал мог что-то подкрутить в ту или иную пользу, мне необходимо обеспечить прозрачность  для его пользователей, чтоб они знали, что, допустим, та часть ПО, которая отвечает за генерирования случайных чисел, никогда не менялась с момента передачи его заказчику. Какие средства могут помочь мне обеспечить это?

Comment: Эм.. Никакие, вроде...

Comment: Могу предложить чисто гипотетический вариант - отталкивать все вычисления и работу внутренностей ПО относительно контрольной суммы кода программы. Но, всё зависит от того как это будет исполнено. Думаю, большинство таких реализаций легко исправить так, чтобы программа продолжала работать не осознавая что её изменили. Если хотите убедиться в том, что это практически нереальная задача, можете поискать CrackMe сайты, которые наглядно показывают что на любые ваши изощрения находятся люди, которые смогут научиться их обходить.

Comment: Сорри, неправильно понял. Если у заказчика есть исходный код - он волен менять что хочет, вы ничего не сможете предпринять. Подкрутить он может не только генератор, но и проверку на то что этот генератор подкрутили, это же исходный код)

Comment: @test123 я не хочу чтоб заказчик обманул своих пользователей, но при этом предоставить ему исходный код програмного обеспечения, это вообще реально?

Comment: Нет, это невозможно. Чтобы вы не сделали, заказчик может это исправить, убрать или переписать. Просто потеряете (ну или немного выиграете) время. Можете сделать запутанный и непонятный код, обфусцировать его, но, заказчик может сделать обратные операции. Просто потратит время, но своего добъётся.

Comment: Договариваетесь, что он платит за исходный код определённой части программы - а другую часть можно предоставить в виде библиотеки. Библиотеку так просто не обратишь в код (если это не с# или java)

Comment: Можно, конечно, попытаться сделать проект левой пяткой используя самые непонятные костыли, желательно такие, чтобы вы сами не понимали как это работает, но чтобы при этом оно работало как часы. Не знаю, хватит ли сил и упёртости чтобы доделать такой проект, но, если заказчик в нём попытается что то изменить - ему проще будет заказать новый, а не переделывать старый) Но, это идеальный случай продуманного, а главное, рабочего говнокода...

Comment: @nick_n_a: >>Библиотеку так просто не обратишь в код<< Вопрос времени, мотивации и средств.

Comment: @test123 c таким же успехом можно не давать исходный код вообще. Да взламывается всё. Думаю что запутанную библиотеку на 5-10 Мб будут расшифровывать год. Есть то что взламывает автомат - то быстро. А если автомата нету - то руцями очень долго.